# Rpart - accuracy of bigrams

Tags: rpart

Good evening, everyone!

I am facing a problem in R. I have a dataset containing Amazon reviews of the Playstation 4 and I would like to create a prediction model with the help of *rpart* and also would like to have the accuracy of this model.

The reviews have been successfully loaded to R, a corpus has been created and some preprocessing tasks have been applied:

```
library(RWeka)
library(tm)
library(rpart)

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tr.review.ps4$reviewText))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
```

The bigrams and a term document matrix are created with the following code:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}
txtTdmBi <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer, bounds = list(global=c(10, Inf))))
```

Then sparse-terms are deleted and a matrix is created:

```
dtm <- removeSparseTerms(txtTdmBi, 0.999)
dtmsparse <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(txtTdmBi))
```

The original dataset consists of 7561 objects. Therefore a training and test set is created as follows:

```
train <- dtmsparse[1:6500,]
test <- dtmsparse[6501:7561,]
```

Then the training is done. $overall refers to the star rating from one to five.

```
train$overall <- tr.review.ps4[1:6500,]$overall
```

When using unigrams the prediction model is created as follows:

```
model <- rpart(overall ~., data = train, method= 'class')
```

However, this is not working in my case because - I guess - the connection to the original review dataset has to be established. But how? I don't have an idea.

When I am entering this code I get following error-output:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Best regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

today I still was searching for a solution of my problem. Luckily I found the mistake.

The errore message occured because the *TermDocumentMatrix* was in the wrong postion.

I had to transpose the matrix with the following code:

```
txtTdmBi.t=t(txtTdmBi)
```

Finally it worked.

Best regards
Paul